# Getting 404 error when trying to POST to express.js server from next.js app

Tags: mongodb, express, post, server, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to create a user registration form in a next.js and send the form to an express.js server. However, when I submit the form, I get a 404 (Not Found) error for the POST http://localhost:3000/api/register` request.

Here's the relevant part of my client-side code:

```js
const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<IFormInput> = async (data) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/register', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }
    const responseData = await response.json();
    console.log(responseData);
    reset();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error', error);
  }
};
```

And here's my server-side code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('./user.model');

mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECTION_STRING)
.then(() => console.log('Connected to database'))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/api/register', async (req, res) => {
    const userData = req.body;
    //Create a user in database
    const user = new User(userData);
    await user.save();
    res.json({ message: 'User registered successfully' });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`))
```

When I submit the form, I get the following error:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/register 404 (Not Found)
```

I've checked that my server is running at `http://localhost:3000` and that the `/api/register` route is defined in my server code. I've also checked that my client-side application can reach my server by opening `http://localhost:3000` in my web browser.

What could be causing this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: try to send an httpRequest via postman and see if that does have a response

Comment: I don't know what your Next config but is it perhaps running on `3000`? Have you tried running express on a different port and send the fetch there. For example run express on `8080` and send `fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/register`.